# Differences between Apple LLVM and LLVM

Tags: macos, llvm

I have Apple's command line tools version 9.1 installed and am working through an LLVM tutorial. I need to use some libraries like llvm/ADT and llvm/IR but get an error when I run the code.

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'llvm/ADT/APFloat.h' file not found
#include "llvm/ADT/APFloat.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I also don't seem to have tools such as the assembler. Are these things not usable with Apple's version? And can I install LLVM without conflicting with Apple's version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's fork misses most of the library,headers and command-line tools in the llvm trunk.
I suggest you compile a new llvm copy from trunk.

Conflicting depends on how you configure everything. You can:

- Install your new copy to global location, where your $PATH configuration is responsible for choosing which version to use.
- Install as a separate Xcode Toolchain.

Here is a build script I've been using:
`cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_APPEND_VC_REV=on -DLLVM_ENABLE_EH=on -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=on -DLLVM_CREATE_XCODE_TOOLCHAIN=on -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/Library/Developer/ ../LLVM`

Running `ninja install` will install to global location, otherwise run `ninja install-xcode-toolchain` to install as a separate toolchain

In your case I suggest installing to global location to avoid the trouble of messing with CFLAGS/LDFLAGS/Header Search Path. Then remove the installation manually after you are done with the tutorial

EDIT: You might also want to check out the official build guide https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html
For your use case, in-tree building is also a feasible option(Providing you are familiar with write cmake configs)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no need to build the LLVM yourself. You can get prebuilt version for your platform here: http://releases.llvm.org

In your case it would be something like this:

```
cd /opt
wget http://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/clang+llvm-5.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz
tar xvf clang+llvm-5.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.xz
mv clang+llvm-5.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin llvm-5.0.0
```

After that you will have everything under `/opt/llvm-5.0.0`, e.g.:

```
/opt/llvm-5.0.0/bin/clang
/opt/llvm-5.0.0/bin/llvm-config
/opt/llvm-5.0.0/lib/libc++.a
```

etc.

P.S. I use `/opt` just as an example, feel free to pick any other directory that fits you best.